# Adding Two's compliment numbers

Tags: assembly

For numbers in two's complement notation, prove that adding two numbers with different signs always produces a valid result

Comment: If you're going to post a homework question, at least word it in a way that sounds like you want an explanation, not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

In two's complement representation, a positive N-bit number *y* is represented as itself and a negative N-bit number with absolute value *x* is represented as *2^N - x*.

Add *y* and *2^N - x*.  You should end up with another number in two's complement representation which looks like *2^N - (...)*.  Work out what that *(...)* is, and you are done.

Not giving the full answer as this appears to be a homework problem.

The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) is not bad, incidentally.  I just went and read it, and that is how I worked out the proof.